# Intellij IDEA: whats the meaning of a green breakpoint?

Tags: debugging, intellij-idea

I have searched through SO, google and the Intellij [docs](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/using-breakpoints.html#breakpoint-icons), but failed to find any mention of green breakpoints
[image]

What does the green mean, and what does the checkmark mean?

Comment: Could you switch to a default theme and check if it's still green or if it has a different colour?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but it is maybe **Idle** icon

[image]

Source : https://jetbrains.design/intellij/resources/icons_list/